# Short story with a cult built around dolls for people living in bunkers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

This was a short story with a Ray Bradbury vibe, centering around a boy and girl hunting rabbits and walking away from the adults.

It also featured information about adults living in bunkers and periodically getting air drops of accessories/furniture for a doll that they had built up a cult/status around.

Comment: This question is very terse and could easily be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 15):

This sounds like it could be one of Philip K. Dick's stories.

He re-used themes quite often and it can be hard to keep track.  The idea of adults playing with dolls in complex set ups is central to [*The Days of Perky Pat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Days_of_Perky_Pat).

Unusually, I was able to lay my hands on my copy pretty easily.  The adults in the story are supported by air drops of supplies after some radiation event.  They obsess over their doll house arrangements (called layouts) for Perky Pat (the doll).  The adults compete to have the best layout.  There are two children who despise how the adults spend their time and go hunting with a home made knife.  They pass up the opportunity to kill a do-cat (dog/cat/mutant thing) and find a kill a rabbit.

The Wikipedia page should give a publication history.  I read it in volume 4 of the collected stories of Philip K. Dick, conveniently called "The Days of Perky Pat".  That probably helped me find it on the shelf.

DavidW has mentioned that you can read the story [online here](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v37n12_1963-12_aMouse/page/n53/mode/2up).

Comment: Nice answer!  Here's the story: https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v37n12_1963-12_aMouse/page/n53/mode/2up

Comment: I knew it was PKD, but I could have sworn he expanded "Perky Pat" into a novel with a different title.

Comment: @Spencer *The Three Stigmata of Palmer Eldritch*